# Guidance on resolving SQLmap suspension during testing

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-injection

When i was scanning a URL for an SQL payload, It kept ending the scan with a "suspended" message, this is the log if you wanna take a look(replaced the actual website name with example for privacy purposes)=

```
[16:31:07] [INFO] testing connection to the target URL
[16:31:07] [WARNING] potential permission problems detected ('Access denied')
[16:31:07] [WARNING] the web server responded with an HTTP error code (403) which could interfere with the results of the tests
[16:31:07] [INFO] checking if the target is protected by some kind of WAF/IPS
[16:31:08] [INFO] testing if the target URL content is stable
[16:31:08] [WARNING] target URL content is not stable (i.e. content differs). sqlmap will base the page comparison on a sequence matcher. If no dynamic nor injectable parameters are detected, or in case of junk results, refer to user's manual paragraph 'Page comparison'
how do you want to proceed? [(C)ontinue/(s)tring/(r)egex/(q)uit] 
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  sqlmap -u example.com/members/register.php?
```

There wasn't much that I could do, I only searched for my problem on Google but the only results that came up where about another problem, even if i specified SQLmap only, it seemed like my problem was unique or something.